# How to properly close a chromote session?

Tags: r, chromote

Using the Linux command `top` I see there are no processes named, "chrome".

Then I do:

```
library("chromote")
   
b <- ChromoteSession$new()
```

and see eight processes called chrome.

Now I close the window/tab:

```
b$close()
# [1] TRUE
```

but the eight processes remain.

I think I want to shutdown the browser process. I tried:

`b$parent$close()`

But this results in the error:

```
# Error in self$send_command(msg, callback = callback_, error = error_,  : 
#                              Chromote object is closed.
```

How do I properly close a Chromote session, created by ChromoteSession$new() so that there are no chrome processes using up memory?

---

Trying @margusl's solution:

```
b <- ChromoteSession$new()

# close session
p <- b$parent
p_browser <- b$parent$get_browser()
p_browser$close()
```

removes all chrome processes but has this error message. Is this a concern?

```
[1] TRUE
[2023-01-22 18:33:15] [error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same behaviour in Windows, though `Browser$close()` apparently kills chrome processes. Getter for browser instance is `b$parent$get_browser()`.

```r
library(chromote)

# Windows tasklist
chrome_tasks <- function(){ 
  system('tasklist /fo csv',intern=TRUE) |> 
    read.csv(text = _) |> 
    subset(Image.Name == "chrome.exe")
}

# chrome tasks before initiating the session:
chrome_tasks()
#> [1] Image.Name   PID          Session.Name Session.     Mem.Usage   
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

# new session:
b <- ChromoteSession$new()
p <- b$parent
p_browser <- b$parent$get_browser()
(ct_session <- chrome_tasks())
#>     Image.Name   PID Session.Name Session. Mem.Usage
#> 279 chrome.exe  9792      Console        1  39 600 K
#> 281 chrome.exe 25336      Console        1   8 380 K
#> 282 chrome.exe 23696      Console        1  36 008 K
#> 283 chrome.exe 16696      Console        1  19 612 K
#> 284 chrome.exe 21244      Console        1  34 916 K
#> 285 chrome.exe 20292      Console        1  36 644 K

# session close()
b$close()
#> [1] TRUE
(ct_bclose <- chrome_tasks())
#>     Image.Name   PID Session.Name Session. Mem.Usage
#> 279 chrome.exe  9792      Console        1  40 392 K
#> 281 chrome.exe 25336      Console        1   8 404 K
#> 282 chrome.exe 23696      Console        1  31 212 K
#> 283 chrome.exe 16696      Console        1  19 676 K
#> 284 chrome.exe 21244      Console        1  34 916 K
# closed: 
setdiff(ct_session$PID, ct_bclose$PID)
#> [1] 20292

# parent close()
p$close()
#> Error in self$send_command(msg, callback = callback_, error = error_, : Chromote object is closed.
(ct_pclose <- chrome_tasks())
#>     Image.Name   PID Session.Name Session. Mem.Usage
#> 279 chrome.exe  9792      Console        1  40 396 K
#> 281 chrome.exe 25336      Console        1   8 404 K
#> 282 chrome.exe 23696      Console        1  31 212 K
#> 283 chrome.exe 16696      Console        1  19 676 K
#> 284 chrome.exe 21244      Console        1  34 916 K
# closed :
setdiff(ct_bclose$PID, ct_pclose$PID)
#> integer(0)

# parent$get_browser() close()
p_browser$close()
#> [1] TRUE
(ct_pbrowser_close <- chrome_tasks())
#> [1] Image.Name   PID          Session.Name Session.     Mem.Usage   
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# closed :
setdiff(ct_pclose$PID, ct_pbrowser_close$PID)
#> [1]  9792 25336 23696 16696 21244
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: See comments in original question.

Comment: @ixodid, not really sure what to make out of this. I get the same error when running in interactive RStudio session or using RScript from RStudio terminal, though when running through `reprex`  it's not present. From the message format format, I assume it's something that websocket client spits out when the other end doesn't gracefully close the connection (i.e chrome process gets killed).